# nest js : Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PlanningService (?)

Tags: nestjs

i'am facing this error when  importing planning.module in app.module :

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PlanningService (?). Please make sure that the argument PlanningMo
del at index [0] is available in the PlanningModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If PlanningModel is a provider, is it part of the current PlanningModule?
- If PlanningModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within PlanningModule?
@Module({
imports: [ /* the Module containing PlanningModel */ ]
})

this is my planning.module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PlanningController } from './planning.controller';
import { PlanningService } from './planning.service';
import {MongooseModule} from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import {PlanningSchema} from "./schemas/planning.schema";
import {UserModule} from "../user/user.module";



@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Planing', schema: PlanningSchema }]),UserModule],
  providers: [PlanningService],
  exports: [PlanningService],
  controllers: [PlanningController]

})


export class PlanningModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import {Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer, RequestMethod} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { mongoConfig } from './config';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { JwtMidelware } from './utils/jwtMidelware';
import {UserController} from "./user/user.controller";

import { TeamModule } from './team/team.module';

import { CompanyModule } from './company/company.module';

import { AgenceModule } from './agence/agence.module';
import { PlanningModule } from './planning/planning.module';


@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(mongoConfig.url, mongoConfig.auth),
    PlanningModule,
    UserModule,
    AuthModule,
    TeamModule,
    CompanyModule,
    AgenceModule,
  ]



})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {

  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
        .apply(JwtMidelware)
        .exclude(
            { path: 'users/id', method: RequestMethod.GET },
        )
        .forRoutes(UserController);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the constructor to the `PlaningService`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel 
constructor(
        @InjectModel('Planning')
        private readonly planningModel: PaginateModel<PlanningDocument>,
    ) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you have `@InjectModel('Planning')` but in your `MongooseModule.forFeature()` you have `{ name:'Planing',...}`. These strings need to match.

Comment: ohh ..yup that was it, i missed it ...thanks for help